# How to get all occurance of a string in clob data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, clob

I have one clob field `'Class_Data'` in my table `'School'` and in the `clob` there is one tag name as `'<Fee-Value>'` , I want to select the all occurrences of the tag from the `clob` data. I used the below query in mysql , but it select only the first occurrence of the tag(there are 12 occurrence of  the vallue)

```
select substr(Class_Data, instr(Class_Data,'Fee-Value'),30) from  School where class='S013' and grade='A' and date ='20130301';
```

The value it is showing is :

```
<Fee-Value>200</Fee-Value>
```

and there are 11 more such kind of tags which are not shown
Please suggest how to do?

Comment: Please add a sample row that you want the query to return, but it currently doesn't

Comment: @Marjeta : It is returning only first row as the instr provide the first index only...

Example
<Fee-Value>200</Fee-Value>

Instead it should return all the tags with name as Fee-Value

Comment: Please add to your question the row that shows and one row that doesn't show.